# ImageButton resize how to do

Tags: java, android, size, imagebutton

I want to resize an ImageButton, but when i change the size of the ImageButton with the mouse on graphical layout on eclipse, and leave the left mouse button, the ImageButton returns to its original size. I have already tried this:

```
android:layout_width="50dip" 
android:layout_height="50dip"
```

But it doesen't work for me.

The problem is that this button should be a hidden button, so i cut a part of background of my app to do this, but when i put this part on my app it is larger, so everyone can see the difference. The problem is that the app resize my background image to make it compatible with the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of `dip` has been replaced by `dp`, which stands for Density Pixel.

Documentation on `dp` can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension)

Answer (score 0):

Try using just 'dp' instead of 'dip'

"dp" is more consistent with "sp".